# 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, file, typeerror, magic-methods

I am having a problem with my code where it always has the error `'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.  Here is my code:

```
def passHack():
    import random
    p1 = random.choice(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"])
    p2 = random.choice(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"])
    p3 = random.choice(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"])
    p4 = random.choice(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"])
    p = (p1 + p2 + p3 + p4)
    g = 0000
    a = 0
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    print "Working..."
    while (g != p):
        a += 1
        f = open('llll.txt')
        g = f[a]
        print g
        f.close()
    if (g == p):
        print "Success!"
        print "Password:"
        print g
        print "Time:"
        print("%s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

def loopPassHack():
    t = 0
    while (t <= 9):
        passHack()
        t += 1
        print "\n"

passHack()
```

I noticed that this happened when I added `g = f[a]`, but I tried adding the attribute `__getitem__` to `g`, `f`, and `a`, but it still returns the same error.  Please help, and thanks if you respond!

Comment: My your identifiers are short. I would recommend not using one letter variable names everywhere, but that's more a good programming practice thing.

Comment: BTW, as a general rule, you should _not_ have `import` statements inside a function, _especially_ if you intend calling the function multiple times. Also, in Python you don't need parentheses around condition expressions, eg `while (g != p):` can be written more cleanly as `while g != p:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message states, file objects do not have a `__getitem__` special method.  This means that you cannot index them like a list because `__getitem__` is the method which handles this operation.

However, you could always read the file into a list before you enter the while-loop:

```
with open('llll.txt') as f:
    fdata = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
while (g != p):
   ...
```

Then, you can index the list of lines as you were:

```
a += 1
g = fdata[a]
print g
```

As an added bonus, we are no longer opening and closing the file with every iteration of the loop.  Instead, it is opened once before the loop starts and then closed as soon as the code block underneath the [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is exited.

Also, the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and is calling [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) on each line to remove any trailing newlines.